# SAS Regression with Specific Parameters in the Variables

Tags: sas, regression, multiple-regression

Good afternoon.

Is it possible to regress variables with specifics, such as Y = X1 (Between Q1 and Q3) X2 (X2 > 100) X3? I do not wish to regress all of the data in X1 or X2, just the data in the parameters that I determine.

What about regressing all the variables between quantiles Q3 and Q4?

Am I approaching this the correct way?

Thank you for your support.

```
 *Regression output;
 ods graphics on;
 proc reg data=mydata PLOTS(ONLY)=(DIAGNOSTICS FITPLOT RESIDUALS);
 model Y = X1 X2 X3; 
 title 'Working Regression Model';
 run;
 ods graphics off;
```

Comment: Where do `Q1` and `Q3` come from?

Comment: First and third quantiles.

Comment: So `Q1` is `P25` is the 25th percentile, right? There are at least two ways of generating these: `proc univariate` and `proc means`.

Comment: Attention: if you create separate regressions for x below its first quantile `P25`, x between its first and third quantile `P25` and `P75` and x above its third quantile, your model will not be continious. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a regression using only part of your data, you can filter it out in your `proc reg` itself:

```
proc reg data=mydata (where=(X1 Between Q1 and Q3 and X2 > 100))
    PLOTS(ONLY)=(DIAGNOSTICS FITPLOT RESIDUALS);
model Y = X1 X2 X3;
```

That is if `Q1` and `Q3`are fields in `myData`. If not, you can create macro variables for them. For instance

```
%let Q1 = 50;
%let Q3 = 250;
proc reg data=mydata (where=(X1 Between &Q1. and &Q3. and X2 > 100))
    PLOTS(ONLY)=(DIAGNOSTICS FITPLOT RESIDUALS);
model Y = X1 X2 X3;
```

This is if you know Q1 and Q3 upfront.

If `Q1` and `Q3`are fields in another dataset, `proc sql` with `select Q1, Q3. into :Q1, :Q3` or a data step with `call symput('Q1', Q1); call symput('Q3', Q3);` can do the job.

### Edit after reading your comment explaining `Q1` etc are quantiles:

The following example might contain all the building blocks you need

```
ods graphics on;
proc means data=SASHELP.CLASS noprint;
    var Height Weight;
    output out=CLASS_Q
        P25(Height Weight)=Height_Q1 Weight_Q1
        P75(Height Weight)=Height_Q3 Weight_Q3;
run;
data _NULL_;
    set CLASS_Q;
    call symput('Height_Q1', Height_Q1);
    call symput('Height_Q3', Height_Q3);
    call symput('Weight_Q1', Weight_Q1);
    call symput('Weight_Q3', Weight_Q3);
run;
%put _user_; *just to debug;
proc reg data=SASHELP.CLASS 
    (where=(Height Between &Height_Q1. and &Height_Q3. and Weight > &Weight_Q1.))
    PLOTS(ONLY)=(DIAGNOSTICS FITPLOT RESIDUALS);
    model Age = Height Weight;
run;
```

Comment: Hi Dirk, thank you for the feedback. I'm trying out these commands right now. The scales for each of the variables are different. Shouldn't that matter when using the macro?

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I will give this a try over the weekend!